# Fitting Keras model with Tensorflow datasets

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm reading [Aurélien Géron's book](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/hands-on-machine-learning/9781492032632/), and on chapter 13, I'm trying to use Tensorflow datasets (rather than Numpy arrays) to train Keras models.

#### 1. The dataset

The dataset comes from [`sklearn.datasets.fetch_california_housing`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.fetch_california_housing.html?highlight=fetch_california_housing#sklearn.datasets.fetch_california_housing), which I've exported to CSV. The first few lines look like this:

```
MedInc,HouseAge,AveRooms,AveBedrms,Population,AveOccup,Latitude,Longitude,MedHouseVal
3.3083,20.0,5.387832699619772,1.0,853.0,3.2433460076045626,37.53,-120.79,1.083
2.1932,29.0,5.164444444444444,1.1288888888888888,726.0,3.2266666666666666,37.53,-120.8,0.906
1.875,15.0,5.327102803738318,1.1495327102803738,189.0,1.766355140186916,37.53,-120.81,1.813
```

As you can see there's 8 features and 1 target (`MedHouseVal`, on the last column).

I reimport it using the following code:

```py
def parse_csv_line(line: bytes) -> Tuple[tf.Tensor, tf.Tensor]:
    parsed = tf.io.decode_csv(line, record_defaults=[0.]*9)
    return parsed[:-1], parsed[-1:]

def load_dataset_csv(paths: Union[str, List[str]]) -> tf.Dataset:
    return tf.data.Dataset.list_files(paths)                        \
        .interleave(lambda p: tf.data.TextLineDataset(p).skip(1))   \
        .map(parse_csv_line)                                        \
        .prefetch(1)

train_set = load_dataset_csv("./housing.train.csv")
val_set = load_dataset_csv("./housing.val.csv")
test_set = load_dataset_csv("./housing.test.csv")
```

So far so good:

```py
>>> list(test_set.take(1))
[(<tf.Tensor: shape=(8,), dtype=float32, numpy=
  array([   3.3083   ,   20.       ,    5.3878326,    1.       ,
          853.       ,    3.243346 ,   37.53     , -120.79     ],
        dtype=float32)>,
  <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([1.083], dtype=float32)>)]
```

#### 2. Model, first try

Then I define my model:

```py
model = keras.models.Sequential(
    [
        keras.layers.Dense(30, input_shape=(8,)),
        keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        keras.layers.Dense(1),
    ],
)
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error")

model.fit(
    train_set,
    epochs=1,  # debugging
    validation_data=val_set,
)
```

but I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_63 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 8 but received input with shape (8, 1)
```

#### 3. Model, second try

If I set the input shape to `(8, 1)` instead of `(8,)`, then I get this warning

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 8, 1) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 8, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_15'), name='input_15', description="created by layer 'input_15'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (8, 1, 1).
```

When I try to make a prediction, I get this weird result:

```py
>>> model.predict(test_set.take(1))

WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 8, 1) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 8, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='dense_159_input'), name='dense_159_input', description="created by layer 'dense_159_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (8, 1, 1).
WARNING:tensorflow:6 out of the last 174 calls to <function Model.make_predict_function.<locals>.predict_function at 0x169f02b80> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
array([[[2.592609 ]],
       [[2.591457 ]],
       [[2.5924652]],
       [[2.592768 ]],
       [[2.533997 ]],
       [[2.5926137]],
       [[2.590248 ]],
       [[2.601169 ]]], dtype=float32)
```

I understand that Tensorflow is displeased with the shape of the tensors, still, why is it giving me 8 predictions?

#### 4. Model, third try

At this point I'm not really sure what to do, so I tried adding a [`Flatten`](https://keras.io/api/layers/reshaping_layers/flatten/) layer:

```py
model = keras.models.Sequential(
    [
        keras.layers.Flatten(),
        keras.layers.Dense(30, input_shape=(8,)),
        keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        keras.layers.Dense(1),
    ],
)
```

This time I get no warning or error, but when I try to make a prediction, I still get 8 results:

```py
>>> model.predict(test_set.take(1))

array([[2.5953178],
       [2.5949838],
       [2.5952766],
       [2.5953639],
       [2.5783124],
       [2.5953195],
       [2.594633 ],
       [2.5978017]], dtype=float32)
```

I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong. Trying to train the first model (with input shape `(8,)` and no `Flatten`) with Numpy arrays instead works just fine.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try batching the dataset. Use `dataset.batch( batch_size )` for Keras models. See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: I have provided a detailed answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as the [official docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential#fit) for `tf.keras.Sequential` suggest, no `batch_size` needs to be provided when `inputs` are instances of `tf.data.Dataset` while calling `tf.keras.Sequential.fit()`,

> Integer or None. Number of samples per gradient update. If
> unspecified, batch_size will default to 32. Do not specify the
> batch_size if your data is in the form of datasets, generators, or
> keras.utils.Sequence instances (since they generate batches).

In case of `tf.data.Dataset`, the `fit()` method expects a batched dataset.

To batch the `tf.data.Dataset`, use the [`batch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#batch) method,

```
batched_ds = ds.batch( batch_size )
```

Thus the dataset will now provide batches of data ( of shape `( batch_size , 8 )` ) instead of the entire data i.e. of shape `( num_samples , 8 )`.

**Tip:**

To unbatch a dataset i.e. to reshape the data to `( num_samples , 8`  again, use the [`unbatch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#unbatch) method provided.